# What is the art depicted on the Magic 6th Edition paper playmats?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-accessories

In the 6th edition Starter Set, the guided game comes with two color-coded playmats. You can also find (very blurry) screencaps below, and [in this instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMxmlgQu4FE&feature=youtu.be&t=170). (I've linked it to the appropriate time, so you should see both playmats within 5 seconds.

I'm trying to find art, source files, or high resolution images of these playmats, so...

**What is the name of the art (or card) wherein the gold wizard is depicted on each of these two playmats?** If that's unavailable, is it possible to identify the artist?

[image: Playmats Classic MtG]

Comment: Maybe just screenshot the video to save people the trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The video that you linked is contained as part of the [Starter 1999 gift box](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Starter_1999/Starter_game_box) that was released back in 1999 and contains:

- 2 40 card decks in cardboard deckboxes
- A poster of [Angel of Light](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=20391)
- Two guides that provide step by step instruction similar to those in the video
- The video that you linked
- two playmats with score keeping beads

It doesn't appear like the featured images are from any cards and are probably just displayed on the box art and playmat as marketing images.

You can see in the image below that they are reflected and colour modified version of each other and featured on the deckboxes as well.

[image: Starter1999 box art]

If you want to see what else is contained in the starter kit you can check out this [Unboxing video](https://youtu.be/P4cLrZJutbw), along with [this visual list of each card](https://scryfall.com/sets/s99) included in the set.

Comment: This is pretty helpful so far. Do you know if there are any artist credits in any of the materials you've found? I think knowing the artist might help me narrow it down if possible. I've updated my question to account for this if you happen to know anything.

Comment: @Robert Without having a physical copy of the kit it is kind of tough. Artist names would be small legal type text around the copyright if included at all. Anything like that would just be a guess from me but I will see if anything comes up. BTW if you click that image the source image is pretty high res (1468x1072).

Comment: @Robert after a quick look around at the [artists that were active during that time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_artists) my best guess is [Ron Spencer](https://scryfall.com/search?page=5&q=a%3A%22Ron+Spencer%22) but only as the Shiny, Muscly, Man with lighting effects seems to be common in his work and he looks to have done a decent amount of work for Wizards..

Comment: Frankly I don't believe for a second that it's Ron Spencer, but I can't thank you enough for the effort. I'm honestly getting a Terese Nielsen vibe, but I could be wrong. I may continue searching and see if I can find a more thorough answer.

Comment: @Robert No problem, and as I said just best guess from the few artists I scanned through. Best of luck with the search, one thing that may be worth a shot is firing off the question to Mark Rosewater at either his [Blogatog](http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/ask) or his twitter @ maro254

Answer (score 2):

So I've looked through the cards from 6th edition and it doesn't match any of those. I'm fairly certain these gold wizards are meant to depict you the player. I can't find any concrete evidence on this, or any additional high res prints of the images, but from my experience with starter sets in the past this was usually the case.

I think sadly these images are lost to time a little. If you could get your hand on a good condition copy of the starter set you could rip the images from there, but otherwise you're a little out of luck sadly.